# Правило для snort

Tags: сеть, фильтры

Здравствуйте.
Нужен фильтр для snort, который позволяет перехватывать SYN-сканирование.
Пробовал использовать вот такое правило:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (flags:S,12; msg:"SYN"; sid: 1231213;)
```

Потом пробую сканировать

```
nmap -sS localhost
```

безрезультатно. Как будет правильно записать такой фильтр?

Answer (score 1):

Безрезультатно в смысле предупреждения не появляются?
У меня всё отрабатывает. Запускал снорт так
sudo snort -A console -i lo -c /etc/snort/snort_sample.conf
после сканирования предупреждения появляются.
Может вы забыли указать интерфейс при запуске?

На правах рекламы: есть такой сайт [emergingthreats.net](http://emergingthreats.net) на котором можно найти и бесплатно скачать более менее свежие правила (проверка на сканирование там тоже есть в scan.rules)